# Values of variables inside a for-loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array `a` defined outside a for-loop. `b` is a variable assigned to be equal to `a` inside the loop. I change the values of `b` inside the loop which also alters `a`. Why/How does this happen?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.asarray(range(10))
>>> for i in range(5,7):
        b = a           #assign b to be equal to a
        b[b<i]=0        #alter b
        b[b>=i]=1
        print a
```

Output:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1] #Unexpected!!
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Why is `a` altered when I don't explicitly do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you do `b = a` only the reference gets copied. Both `a` and `b` point to the same object.

If you really want to create a copy of `a` you need to do for example:

```
import copy
...
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Comment: As `a` is a Numpy array just `b = a.copy()` is enough.

Comment: Is this limited only to loops?
when i do  a = 5  b = a  b+=1  print a . The output is still 5

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.asarray` is mutable so, `a` and `b` pointed one location.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> id(a)
140435835060736
>>> id(b)
140435835060736
```

You can fix like this `b = a[:]` or `b = copy.deepcopy(a)`

[`id`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) returns the “**identity**” of an object.

Comment: Are the identities same only for lists/arrays?

Comment: @AdarshChavakula Python doesn't have a native array data structure, but it has the list which is much more general and can be used as a multidimensional array quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *slice* operator to make a copy. `=` just gives it another name as it copies references.

```
b = a[:]
```

Will work fine.

---

According to @AshwiniChaudhary's comment, this won't work for Numpy arrays, the solution in this case is to

```
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Comment: Slicing returns a view in case of Numpy arrays not copy.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Didn't notice Numpy, thanks. Edited.